# How do I know if Chrome open debugger(F12)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to know whether the debugger mode F12 is turned on in Chrome. Most methods use JavaScript, but it is not suitable for me, because I want to check it from another running app on my pc. Are there other characteristics to identify? Such as special file operations.

Comment: What browser? From where? From within a web page? From another app running on the same computer?

Comment: Since detecting an undocked devtools window is rather simple, I guess the problem is detecting the [standard] docked devtools. You can use the low-level accessibility API of your OS. See `chrome://accessibility` and https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/accessibility.